# in gimp, is there a way to use the same save-as dialog for ANY file type?

Tags: gimp

The old Gimp versions (before 2.7) had only 1 "save" dialog.

The user could choose to save as XCF or any other format, either by selecting a format from the drop-down, or by specifying an extension manually.

since 2.7, novice users will save always in XCF, but then power users like me have to use different set of key-binding and different dialogs for each type of save, and it's both annoying and cumbersome.

Is there any setting or trick to use the same save-as dialog for ANY file type, like it was before??

Comment: I always use export dialog.

Comment: but i sometimes want to save XCF.

Answer (score 3):

The functionality you're used to is now available by choosing `File` > `Export`.

There's no way to get the old functionality back, aside from hacking the source code. I agree that this change is quite annoying for long-time Gimp users.